# AspectJ in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial WITHOUT using APT-GET?

Tags: apt, 16.04

Ola,

I am a newbie to Linux, presently working on setting up the platform for development. I managed to setup almost all what I need, except AspectJ. I was just wondering if there is a way that I could get AspectJ installed in my Xenial, without using the apt-get, may be extracting a tarball and configuring it.

Now I know for a fact that using apt-get is the most convenient. But I need to get the software installed in a single location, which would make migration in case of an emergency easier. I have been googling around to find a feasible solution, yet I couldn't find out one. To summarize what I am looking for,

```
1.from where I can find a tarball for AspectJ.
2.is there a way that I can funnel the setup to a preferred directory in apt-get?
```

Comment: Maybe download it from http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php?

Comment: Done. What's next? I am clueless! :D

Comment: There is a section about installation in that page, which I think is pretty clear.